# my bot doesn't accept my string array for mod. does anyone know whats wrong with it?

Tags: java, command, irc, twitch, pircbot

when "the_pvbro" wants to type a command in chat the bot doesn't allow him to use it. and i'm too lazy to make a new class for every new mod i add.
so does anyone have an idea maybe how to do it differntly?

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;
```

public class TwitchBot extends PircBot{

```
public TwitchBot(){
    this.setName("rayibot");

    this.isConnected();
}

String owner = "skalrayi";
String mod [] = new String[3];{
    mod[0] = "the_pvbro";
}


public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message){
    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("!spiel")){
        sendMessage(channel, "Aktuell wird " + Config.currentGame + " gespielt.");
    }

    else 
    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("!song")){
        sendMessage(channel, "Aktueller Song:" );

    }

    else
    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("!hallo")){
        sendMessage(channel, "Hallo wie geht es dir denn heute so " +sender);
    }

    else
    if(message.startsWith("!kick")){
        if(sender.equals(owner) || sender.equals(mod))
        {

            String userToKick = message.split(" ")[1];
            kick(channel, userToKick );
            sendMessage(channel, ".timeout " +userToKick + " 60");
            sendMessage(channel, userToKick +" wurde aus dem Channel gekickt!");
        }

        else{
            sendMessage(channel, "Deine Rechte reichen nicht aus, um diesen Befehl zu benutzen! " + sender);
        }
    }

     if (message.startsWith("!ban")) {
            if(sender.equals(owner)|| sender.equals(mod))
            {
                String userToBan = message.split(" ")[1];
                ban(channel, userToBan);
                sendMessage(channel, ".ban " + userToBan);
                sendMessage(channel, userToBan + " wurde aus dem Channel verbannt!");
            }
            else{
                sendMessage(channel, "Deine Rechte reichen nicht aus, um diesen Befehl zu benutzen! " + sender );
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are comparing the `String` sender against the mod array. This will always return `false`, since a String is not an array. What you want to do is check if the mod array *contains* the sender string.

What I would do is use a list instead of an array by replacing:

```
String mod [] = new String[3];{
    mod[0] = "the_pvbro";
}
```

with

```
List<String> mod = Arrays.asList("the_pvbro");
```

Then you'll be able to use the `contains` method by replacing:

```
sender.equals(mod)
```

with

```
mod.contains(sender);
```

This way, when you get more mods, you can just add them to the arguments to `Arrays.asList()`, i.e.:

```
List<String> mod = Arrays.asList(
    "the_pvbro",
    "mod2",
    "mod3");
```

Comment: thanks for answering and explaining. everything works fine now,

Comment: @Skalrayi No problem. Consider clicking the checkmark under the vote buttons if you feel that I have sufficiently answered your question :)